# Custom site template using default masterpage

Tags: sharepoint-online

Created site template in SharePoint Online by using save as template. Unfortunately newly created custom site template using default master page

To solve this issue I have edited Onet.xml (Edited cab) file and uploaded back but still site template using default masterpage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I cannot explain the behavior, I can recommend a solution that is fully supported by Microsoft and the community. For any type of SharePoint (on-prem or online) site templates, you should be using the PnP Remote Provisioning. It is FAR superior to the horrible process of using "Save Site as Template".

You can get started here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/pnp-remote-provisioning